# Does await guarantee execution order?

Tags: python-asyncio

Consider a single-threaded Python program. A coroutine named "first" is blocked on I/O. The subsequent instruction is "await second." Is the coroutine "second" guaranteed to execute immediately until it blocks on I/O? Or, can "first" resume executing (due to the I/O operation completing) before "second" is invoked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asyncio implemented a way that `second` would start executing until it would return control to event loop (it usually happens when it reaches some I/O operation) and only after it `first` can be resumed. I don't think it somehow guaranteed to you, but hardly believe this implementation will be changed either.

If for some reason you don't want `first` to resume executing until some part of `second` reached, it's probably better explicitly to use [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock) to block `first` from executing before moment you want.

Example to show when control returns to event loop and execution flow can be changed:

```
import asyncio


async def async_print(text):
    print(text)


async def first():
    await async_print('first 1')
    await async_print('first 2')
    await asyncio.sleep(0)  # returning control to event loop
    await async_print('first 3')


async def second():
    await async_print('second 1')
    await async_print('second 2')
    await asyncio.sleep(0)  # returning control to event loop
    await async_print('second 3')


async def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(first())
    asyncio.ensure_future(second())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

Output:

```
first 1
first 2
second 1
second 2
first 3
second 3
```

Comment: Thank you. I was mainly concerned about the amount of time that could elapse between 'await' and the awaited thingy executing. If it could take seconds due to some I/O that I don't necessarily know about, asyncio would be useless. I'm happy.