# Call a coroutine without yielding the event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I may break the code up for readability reasons. So

```
async coro_top():
  print('top')
  print('1')
  # ... More asyncio code

  print('2')
  # ... More asyncio code
```

... into something like

```
async coro_top():
  print('top')
  await coro_1()
  await coro_2()

async coro_1()
  print('1')
  # ... More asyncio code

async coro_2()
  print('2')
  # ... More asyncio code
```

However, the extra `await`s mean that these are not strictly equivalent

- Another concurrent task can run code between `print('top')` and `print('1')`, so makes race conditions a touch more likely for certain algorithms.
- There is (presumably) a slight overhead in yielding the event loop

So is there a way of calling a coroutine without yielding the event loop in order to avoid the above?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427152/does-await-guarantee-execution-order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The premise of the question is incorrect: contrary to what people tend to expect, an `await` **doesn't** automatically yield to the event loop. You can easily test that:

```
async def noop():
    pass

async def busy_loop(msg):
    while True:
        print(msg)
        await noop()

# keeps printing 'a', the event loop is stuck
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(busy_loop('a'), busy_loop('b')))
```

Although `busy_loop` awaits the whole time, it still blocks the event loop, so that other tasks will not run, and even cancelling it is impossible. This is because the `noop` coroutine it awaits never suspends execution.

`await some_coroutine()` doesn't mean "schedule `some_coroutine()` and yield to the event loop, resuming when it completes". It means "start executing `some_coroutine()` and, **if/when it chooses to suspend, suspend along**", and assuming the former can [lead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377822/1600898) to [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816319/1600898).

In other words, the broken-up code really is equivalent to the code before the refactoring. The only way for another task to execute between `print('top')` and `print('1')` is for a new `await` to be added between them (one that actually suspends the coroutine), but the same can be said of the original code as well.

> There is (presumably) a slight overhead in yielding the event loop

The overhead exists, but it is comparable to the overhead of a function call, not to the significantly larger overhead of running an iteration of the event loop.

Comment: Thanks! (I have been programming with asyncio Python for a while now, and I am slightly embarrassed that I didn’t understand this as well as I thought I did...)